# ListIterator kind for Set

Tags: iterator

ListIterator can be used to traverse in both ways over the List.

Why don't we have something similar to ListIterator  for Set? Is it because it is not ordered? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Yes, because it's not ordered.

---

**Long answer:**

**LISTS**

In a singly linked `List` every element has a reference to its following element. 
In a doubly linked `List` every element has a reference to its successor and its predecessor. 
So it is easy to implement the `next` method of a `Iterator`. To iterate a list we just run through the next references of the list elements. A traverse iteration in a doubly linked list will run the pred. references. In a singly linked list, the list order will be inverted and iterated.
So a order is defined.

[image]

([src](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/All_Chapters))

---

**SETS**

A `Set` is managed by a HashFunction

[image]

([src](http://www.thecshandbook.com/Hash_Set))

The advantage is, that the lookup function in a set improves to O(1). But we loose the references between the set elements. So it gets harder to iterate in both ways over the Set in both ways. There are ways to iterate this Set. But to traverse over the Set we need to define an order. But it is not.